# Invalid flowchart xml definition in Grafana

Tags: grafana, flowchart

My Grafana instance always receives an error when using the flowchart. When editing the xml I receive

```
Invalid Xml definition
```

I can use any xml from draw.io and I receive this error.

E.G.

```
<mxGraphModel dx="1407" dy="920" grid="1" gridSize="10" guides="1" tooltips="1" connect="1" arrows="1" fold="1" page="1" pageScale="1" pageWidth="850" pageHeight="1100" math="0" shadow="0">
  <root>
    <mxCell id="0" />
    <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />
    <mxCell id="840GHtpYckpoDqrtnk2p-1" value="FUN TIMES" style="shape=dataStorage;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;fixedSize=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="100" y="300" width="100" height="80" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="840GHtpYckpoDqrtnk2p-3" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;entryX=0.59;entryY=1.013;entryDx=0;entryDy=0;entryPerimeter=0;" edge="1" parent="1" source="840GHtpYckpoDqrtnk2p-2" target="840GHtpYckpoDqrtnk2p-1">
      <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry">
        <mxPoint x="170" y="490" as="targetPoint" />
        <Array as="points">
          <mxPoint x="240" y="260" />
          <mxPoint x="240" y="430" />
          <mxPoint x="120" y="430" />
          <mxPoint x="120" y="490" />
          <mxPoint x="159" y="490" />
        </Array>
      </mxGeometry>
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="840GHtpYckpoDqrtnk2p-5" value="" style="edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle;rounded=0;orthogonalLoop=1;jettySize=auto;html=1;" edge="1" parent="1" source="840GHtpYckpoDqrtnk2p-2" target="840GHtpYckpoDqrtnk2p-4">
      <mxGeometry relative="1" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="840GHtpYckpoDqrtnk2p-2" value="ME" style="shape=umlActor;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;html=1;outlineConnect=0;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="310" y="230" width="30" height="60" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
    <mxCell id="840GHtpYckpoDqrtnk2p-4" value="PRESTON" style="shape=umlActor;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;html=1;outlineConnect=0;" vertex="1" parent="1">
      <mxGeometry x="380" y="230" width="30" height="60" as="geometry" />
    </mxCell>
  </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

this works in grafana cloud

In the logs I found

```
logger=context userId=88 orgId=1 uname=bkauffman7 t=2022-09-15T20:40:47.27209224Z level=error msg="Plugin file not found" error="open /var/lib/grafana/plugins/agenty-flowcharting-panel/module.js.map: no such file or directory" traceID=
```

Answer (score 1):

@Brandon_Kauffman, I stumbled on your question while trying to solve my own. I believe that you can use the [Grafana Infinity plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/yesoreyeram-infinity-datasource/) to read and use XML data. [Here](https://sriramajeyam.com/grafana-infinity-datasource/wiki/xml/) is documentation specific to XML. I hope this helps!

Comment: Did that solve the error for flowchart or did it originate somewhere else?

Comment: @BrandonKauffman I have not yet gotten the plugin to read XML data. In addition to my data, I have tried following the tutorial, so I am not certain what I am doing wrong. I will follow up if I figure it out or you can follow the discussion here https://github.com/yesoreyeram/grafana-infinity-datasource/issues/410